# MySQL Request is not properly inserting into database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

**The answer and question here is no longer considered good practice. Refer to other posts.**

Comment: Please post your code, not pictures of your code.

Comment: Made the edit. @AlexHowansky

Comment: Give a space after INSERT INTO gallery. :) and after VALUES.

Comment: It didn't make a difference, @NeerajSingh

Comment: @Ryan Wrong SQL statements always make differences. .. Try to execute DRY Query with Same Statement...you will get query error...

Comment: I tested it with my methods, it didn't work. @NeerajSingh - Thus forth I need something else, as I am not willing to change SQL methods.

Comment: code is valid, your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Bloody code. @WheatBeak :)

Answer (score 0):

Bingo.
http://prntscr.com/fknta0

"desc" is MYSQL Reserved.